# How to give the 1D input to Convolutional Neural Network(CNN) using Keras?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm solving a regression problem with Convolutional Neural Network(CNN) using Keras library. I have gone through many examples but failed to understand the concept of input shape to 1D Convolution

This my data set, 1 target variable with 3 raw signals.

[image: The data set contains the stream of sensor generated value. It has 4 columns(3 sensor values & 1 target variable) and 1 millon rows(have 18000 segments)]

For visualization the 5 segments of sensor signal are shown here, each segment has its own meaning

[image: For visualization the 5 segments of sensor signal are shown here, each segment has its own meaning]

I want to give segment wise sensor values as input to the 1D Convolution layer but problem is that segments are of varibale length.

This is my CNN architecture

[image: This is my CNN architecture]

I tired to build my CNN model but confused

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(5, 7, activation='relu',input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_length=4))
model.add(Conv1D(4, 7, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
```

So, How can I give input to Conv1D of CNN in Keras? OR should I set fixed size input to Conv1D? but how?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the input_shape should be **(time_steps, n_features)**, where time_steps would be the length of the segments (sequence of sensor signals) and n_features the number of channels (3 in your case, as you have 3 different sensors).

Therefore, the input to your network should have 3 dimensions **(batch, steps, channels)**, where batch is the different segments.

I've only worked with fixed time_steps, If you really can't use segments with same length you might try to pad them with zeros.

On the [Keras Documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv1d) they say that you may use **(None, 3)** as the input_shape for variable-length sequences of 3-dimensional vectors, but I never used this way.